# Stay logged in(save session) in new browser with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pickle

So, I am trying to:

1. Open browser
2. Log-In to website
3. Save session/cookies
4. Close browser
5. Open new browser
6. Load session/cookies and get logged in

I am trying to do this for hours, and it looks like old code from the internet doesn't work.

Code example:

```
import pickle
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

# I am using website ascension.gg to test it, as it is very simple
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
browser.get('https://ascension.gg/')
time.sleep(20) # during this time, I log in manually
pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies() , open("asc2.pkl","wb")) # save cookies/session ideally
browser.quit()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
browser.get('https://ascension.gg/')
for cookie in pickle.load(open("asc2.pkl", "rb")):
    browser.add_cookie(cookie) # load cookies and restore session
browser.refresh() # logged in back ( doesn't work )
```

Any help? Why this doesn't work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

How about using the `chrome profile`, which internally handles cookies.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
# location for a chrome profile creation/access
options.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=/home/your_id/CHROME_STORAGE");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This code creates a save location for a profile (including a space for cookies). You do not need to write any manual codes for handling cookies with the above code. Instead, Chrome will handle cookies.

Comment: I know for this solution, but this is not what I need. I do not want to use my default Chrome browser/profile, I want to load create new with Selenium and then load it into other Selenium browser.